# IE input radio value always returns 'on' instead of the value set

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer

I'm creating a form dynamically and appending elements as such:

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.name = extension_id + '[]';
input.value = value.id;
input.className = 'changeable';
input.type = 'radio';
input.checked = true;
wrapper_div.appendChild(input);
```

As an example of the HTML produced (this is from Chrome):

```
<input name="2[]" class="changeable" type="radio" value="5">
```

In Chrome and Firefox, the javascript:

```
document.getElementsByName("2[]")[0].value
```

returns '5' as expected, but in IE (IE9 in my test) it returns 'on'.

Is there some reason why IE is ignoring the value set, and instead returning the checked status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, it's not so much a matter of the value being ignored, as one of IE treating the element as the object it is - a radio button, and initializing it as such.

If you open up the debugger and step through the code, you can see that the value 5 does indeed get set. When you get to the line that sets the type of input it is, I.e `input.type='radio'` you can see this value change from 5 to 'on'. Think of it as IE calling the constructor for a radio-button the moment it knows the input is indeed a radio button.

The fix?

Easy enough in this case, just change the order of your statements. Yup! Simple as that. Set the type, *then* set the value.

This works okay in IE9 and Chrome.

```
{
    var extension_id = 2;
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.name = extension_id + '[]';
    input.type = 'radio';
    input.checked = true;
    input.value = 5;
    input.className = 'changeable';
    document.body.appendChild(input);

    alert(input.value);
}
```

Oh, and before I forget - you can open the debugger in IE with F12. - There's plenty of videos around on how to use it. :)

Comment: Thank you! I guess I didn't expect the order to matter, good to know.  Thanks for the tip about the debugger too.

Comment: Can't believe IE11 is still affected by this, what a garbage browser. Fix does indeed work though, thank you!